# Adding values to the keys in Map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I have a record

```
record = [ [ name1:'value1', name2:'value2', name3:'value3' ],
           [ name1:'value6', name2:'value7', name3:'value8' ] ]
```

I would like to add two more key/value pairs to with values as boolean(true/false) as below

```
record = [ [ name1:'value1', name2:'value2', name3:'value3', name4:false, name5:true ],   
           [ name1:'value6', name2:'value7', name3:'value8', name4:false, name5:true ] ]
```

When I tried to use add or put functions, doesnt seem to work(either replacing the existing values or not doing anything)

Comment: I wouldn't keep tagging these as `java`, they're groovy questions

Comment: Also, it makes things easier if you post valid groovy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
record = record.collect { it + [ name4:false, name5:true ]  }
```

Or you can also do:

```
record = record*.plus( name4:false, name5:true )
```

Comment: Thanks for removing the Java tag and for your answer ... as always...cheers

Answer (score 0):

To add to Patricks answer above (+1), a Map contains a set not a list so all keys must be unique. So you cannot assign multiple values to a single key directly.

Among many solutions, you can alternatively, save an object:

```
Map<String, myObject>
```

that holds many different values and this will still maintain the uniqueness of the set since there will only be one key.